# value is not inserting into database and the code is free from error

Tags: php, mysql

This is what I have done in my coding part. The code is free from errors but the values are not inserting

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$cname = $_POST['cname'];
$caddr = $_POST['caddr'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$cpassword = $_POST['cpassword'];
$target_path = "upload/";
$target_path = $target_path.basename($_FILES['photo']['name']); 

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target_path);
$str = "WEB";
$cnt = "SELECT COUNT(no) AS count FROM user";
$result = mysql_query($cnt);
$row = mysql_fetch_object($result);
$res = $row->count;
$res = $res+1;
$uid = $str.$res;
if($password==$cpassword) {
mysql_query("insert into user (no, uid, name, password, cpassword, photo) values('$res', '$uid', '$name', '$password', '$cpassword', '$target_path', now())");

}
```

Comment: That code is far from "free from error"... The very first step to do is to actually *check* for any errors. http://php.net/mysql_error

Comment: Then, mandatory reading http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php and [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13944956)

Comment: you insert query is wrong. Please check it. you wrote 6 column name and value is 7. hows possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check you insert query , you have mentioned only 6 fields in insert statement but provided 7 values in insert statement. Updated query is below.

```
mysql_query("insert into user (no,uid,name,password,cpassword,photo) values('".$res."','".$uid."','".$name."','".$password."','".$cpassword."','".$target_path."')");
```

Answer (score 1):

Error in your insert query. column mismatch while in insertion.

```
mysql_query("insert into user (no,uid,name,password,cpassword,photo) values('$res','$uid','$name','$password','$cpassword','$target_path',now())");
```

These are 6 `no,uid,name,password,cpassword,photo` column you are assigning to insert value but in second part you are inserting value in  7 column

As already mentions in your question comment regarding `mysql_*` has been deprecated. and here are your query part to catch `mysql_error`

```
$sql = "insert into user (no,uid,name,password,cpassword,photo) values('$res','$uid','$name','$password','$cpassword','$target_path',now())";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
```

Comment: It would be infinitely more productive to teach the OP how to check for such errors themselves, and what else is wrong with their approach

Comment: I agree with you. OP should be take care such basic thing. I will update answer with debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You have given an extra entry in values in query. Field name for time is missing.

```
mysql_query("insert into user (no,uid,name,password,cpassword,photo) values('$res','$uid','$name','$password','$cpassword','$target_path',now())");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your insert query is wrong. You have given six column names but values for them respectively are seven.

In your insert query the last value `now()` this is extra. You have not specified in which column it will get inserted. Specify that.

Answer (score 1):

Try it it will  work if any issue check your data base  field type an d pass the value accordingly

```
  mysql_query("insert into user (no, uid, name, password, cpassword, photo) values('$res', '$uid', '$name', '$password', '$cpassword', '$target_path')");
```